# Sitecore get items under current item

Tags: templates, sitecore

I would like to have a query to use in a sitecore template field (multilist) that will populate the list with items of a specific template id that only exist under the current item.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the children of your item using query like:

```
query:./*[@@templateid='{SOME TEMPLATE ID}']
```

or all descendants

```
query:.//*[@@templateid='{SOME TEMPLATE ID}']
```

Comment: Thanks Marek.  Unfortunately this didn't work for me.  Here is the query I used in the content editor template field:    query:./*[@@templateid='{C3E067D2-8E15-4294-934B-B53B537894F6}']    The only items showing in the left half to select from were sitecore items such as sitecore root, various system folders, the layout folder.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon.  Turns out the syntax I used was not entirely reliable.  Only some of the items in the list are available.  I have a multi list with search box and 1 of the 4 items in the list show.  the others with the same template id do not show.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found that works for me:  TemplateFilter={C3E067D2-8E15-4294-934B-B53B537894F6}&StartSearchLocation=query:./* .   Basically the same just with a different syntax.  Thanks again Marek

Comment: I think this answer is almost correct. `StartSearchLocation` should always point to a single item. Try maybe `TemplateFilter={C3E067D2-8E15-4294-934B-B53B537894F6}&StartSearchLocation=query:.`. And if this doesn't work, check if there is anything in the logs. Sitecore adds quite nice messages when there is any issue with Multilist field